# CSS How to check if an attribute name on HTML element itself (not the value) exists or matches some pattern?

Tags: css, regex, css-selectors, attributes

lets say I have different div elements in HTML with different "data-something" attributes.

now, I want to check for all data-something attributes and check if they are present on the elements...

```
<div data-test1></div>
<div data-test2></div>
```

...etc.
I know that it's possible to check the value of attributes in css for some pattern matches, e.g

```
div[data-test1*="value"]
```

but how do I check the attribute itself if its present on some element, based on some regex match, e.g like matching the suffix `data-test*`, then then I color all divs background green on the elements that have those matching attributes present on themselves (just an example)...

Is there some way to  do that?

Comment: Do you mean find them on the page using a selector and then count the number of results?

Comment: no I just mean finding any of them with a selector and then e.g manipulate all the elements with that attribute by setting some style or so... or maybe also count, doesnt matter...